# Storing order details in MYSQL database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to learn php and MYSQL through developing an eCommerce website. So far the experience with these new languages are really good, but I'm stuck on one of my ideas. I have managed to add the order details to my database, however it adds only a product at a time. Originally what I wanted to do is to add more than a product and store it in a database.

For an example let's say an user wants to buy 5 items. How can I store this into my database. With my current code this just add as a single product with the total of 5 products.(Even the quantity is not adding up).

I'm not sure whether my code is correct. Any suggestions on this is really appreciated. (Please feel free to modify code, it will be really helpful)

Following is the code I'm using to add orders to database.

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h4 class="text-center">Paypal Intergration Goes Here.</h4>
  <img src="./images/paywith_paypal.png" class="img-responsive  center-block" alt="Pay With Paypal">


  <?php
// Getting product details
$total = 0;
global $con;
$ip = getIp();

$sel_price = "SELECT * FROM zeus_limited.cart WHERE ip_address='$ip'";
$run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price);

while($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)){
  $product_id = $p_price['cart_product_id'];
  $product_price = "SELECT * FROM zeus_limited.product WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
  $run_product_price = mysqli_query($con,$product_price);

  while ($prod_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_product_price)){
    $product_price = array($prod_price['product_price']);
    $product_id = $prod_price['product_id'];
    $pro_name = $prod_price['product_title'];
    $values = array_sum($product_price);
    $total +=$values;
  }
}

// Getting Quantity from cart
$get_quantity = "SELECT * FROM zeus_limited.cart WHERE cart_product_id='$product_id'";
$show_quantity = mysqli_query($con, $get_quantity);
$row_qty = mysqli_fetch_array($show_quantity);
$quantity = $row_qty['quantity'];
if($quantity == 0){
  $quantity = 1;
}
else {
  $quantity = $quantity;
  $total = $total * $quantity;
}

// Getting Customer details
$user = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
$get_customer = "SELECT * FROM zeus_limited.customer WHERE customer_email='$user'";
$show_customer = mysqli_query($con, $get_customer);
$row_c = mysqli_fetch_array($show_customer);

$customer_id = $row_c['customer_id'];
$customer_email = $row_c['customer_email'];
$customer_name = $row_c['customer_fname'];

$trx_id = mt_rand();
$currency = 'USD';
$invoice = mt_rand();


// Insert data to ORDER table
$add_order = "INSERT INTO zeus_limited.orders (order_product_id, order_customer_id, order_quantity, invoice_no, status, order_date) VALUES ('$product_id','$customer_id','$quantity','$invoice','in Progress',NOW())";
$run_order = mysqli_query($con, $add_order);

// Insert data to PAYMENT table
$add_payment = "INSERT INTO zeus_limited.payment (amount, payment_customer_id, payment_product_id, trx_id, payment_currency, payment_date) VALUES ('$total','$customer_id','$product_id','$trx_id','$currency',NOW())";
$run_payment = mysqli_query($con, $add_payment);

// Removing products from CART
$empty_cart = "DELETE FROM zeus_limited.cart";
$show_customerart = mysqli_query($con, $empty_cart);


if($total == $total){
  echo "<div class='text-center'>";
  echo "<h3>Welcome:" . $_SESSION['customer_email']. "<br>" . "Hooray! Your Payment was successful!</h3>";
  echo "<a href='./customer/my_account.php'>Go to your Account</a><br>";
  echo "</div>";

}
else {
  echo "<div class='text-center'>";
  echo "<h4>Welcome Guest, Payment process failed... Please try again</h4><br>";
  echo "<a href='/shop_products.php'>Go to Back to shop</a>";
  echo "</div>";
}

?>
</div>
```

I'm attaching the cart code as well.(if it's needed)

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once './includes/init.php';
require_once './functions/functions.php';

echo getCart();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Zeus Pvt. Ltd</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container container-bg">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="zeus_cart">
            <div class="cart_bg">
              <ul class="cart">
                <i class="cart_icon"></i><p class="cart_desc"><?php getTotalCartPrice() ?><br><span class="yellow"><?php getTotalItems() ?></span></p>
                <div class='clearfix'></div>
              </ul>
              <ul class="product_control_buttons">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/close.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class='clearfix'></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="quick_access">
              <li class="view_cart"><a href="cart.php">View Cart</a></li>
              <li class="check"><a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a></li>
              <div class='clearfix'></div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container container-bg">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="shop_products.php">Shop Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="customer/my_account.php">My Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li>
                <?php
                if(!isset($_SESSION['customer_email'])){
                  echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
                }
                else {
                  echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
                }
                ?>
              </li>
              <li class="welcome"><a>Welcome <?php echo getUsername(); ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
              <div class="form-group search">
                <input type="text" name="user_query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Products">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-search"></button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container container-bg">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="shoppingcart-title">
            <h4 class="text-center sidebar-main-menu">Shopping Cart</h4>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Product No.</th>
                      <th>Product(s)</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                      <th>Unit Price</th>
                      <th>Sub Total</th>
                      <th>Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                </tbody>
                <?php
                global $con;

                $total = 0;
                $ip = getIp();
                $select_price = "SELECT * FROM zeus_limited.cart WHERE zeus_limited.cart.ip_address='$ip'";
                $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $select_price);

                while ($product_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

                  $product_id = $product_price['cart_product_id'];
                  $product_quantity = $product_price['quantity'];
                  $product_price = "SELECT * FROM zeus_limited.product WHERE zeus_limited.product.product_id ='$product_id'";
                  $run_product_price = mysqli_query($con, $product_price);

                  while ($product_new_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_product_price)) {

                    $product_price = array($product_new_price['product_price']);
                    $product_id = $product_new_price['product_id'];
                    $product_image = $product_new_price['product_image_carousel'];
                    $product_title = $product_new_price['product_title'];
                    $unit_product_price = $product_new_price['product_price'];

                    $values = array_sum($product_price);
                    $total += $values * $product_quantity;

                    ?>

                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $product_id; ?></td>
                      <td><img src="images/products/<?php echo $product_image; ?>" </td>
                      <td><?php echo $product_title; ?></td>
                      <td><input id="" type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product_id; ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" style="text-align:center;"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id[<?php echo $product_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"
                      </td>

                      <!--Updating the quantity-->
                      <?php
                      $ip = getIp();

                      if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

                        foreach ($_POST['product_id'] as $pid => $id) {

                          $product_id = $id;
                          $product_quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$pid];
                          $update_products = "UPDATE zeus_limited.cart SET quantity = '$product_quantity' WHERE cart_product_id = '$product_id' AND ip_address = '$ip';";
                          $run_update = mysqli_query($con, $update_products);
                        }
                        if($update_products){

                          echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
                        }
                      }
                      ?>

                      <td><?php echo 'Rs '. $unit_product_price; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo 'Rs '.$unit_product_price * $product_quantity  ?></td>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <?php } } ?>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Grand Total: </th>
                      <th><?php echo 'Rs '. $total ?></th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
                <div class="cart_buttons">
                  <input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart"/>
                  <input type="submit" name="continue_shopping" value="Continue Shopping"/>
                  <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout"/>
                  <?php if (isset($_POST['checkout'])){echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>"; } ?>
                </div>
              </form>
              <?php
              global $con;
              $ip = getIp();

              if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
                foreach ($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {

                  $delete_product = "DELETE FROM zeus_limited.cart WHERE cart_product_id='$remove_id' AND ip_address='$ip'";
                  $run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_product);

                  if($run_delete){

                    echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
                  }
                }
              }

              if (isset($_POST['continue_shopping'])){

                echo "<script>window.open('shop_products.php','_self')</script>";
              }
            ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 footer-grid">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <ul class="list1">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="shop_product.php">Shop Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="customer/my_account.php">My Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 footer-grid">
        <h3>Your Account</h3>
        <ul class="list1">
          <li><a href="#">My Orders</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delete Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 footer-grid">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p class="footer_desc">Zeus is a pharmacy focused on providing patients with what they need and deserve - exceptional pharmacy care. It is our responsibility and passion to care for your medication needs.</p>
        <p class="f_text"><span class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Phone:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+081 123 45 67</p>
        <p class="email"><span class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>info@zeuspharmacy.com</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 footer-grid-bottom">
        <div class="copyrights">
          <p>&copy; 2017 Zeus Pharmacy. Made with <span class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> by <a href="https://dilumtharaka.github.io">Dilum Tharaka</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[order table structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ZcV.png)

[payment table structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKoQm.png)

Above are the table structures I'm using. Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note, I would not use ip to handle the cart since multiple users can come from the same ip =)

Comment: You should have an `orders` table, and then also an `order_products` table, which has `order_id` and `product_id` (assuming you already have a `products` table, of course)

Comment: The short answer is you need to move your `INSERT` statement into your cart loop; otherwise, you are only inserting the most recent iteration of the loop.

Comment: @waterloomatt Can you show me how it's done by modifying the code please?

Comment: Sorry I can't. There is a bit too much wrong here. What you want to do is to loop over the cart items and insert each one as an order line. I agree with @PatrickQ in that your table structure is wrong. There are many good (and bad) tutorials on how to build and structure a shopping cart application.

Comment: @PatrickQ Why should I use separate order_products table?

Comment: @ColinFernando Because that's a pretty typical setup.  You have products, you have orders, and then you have the products that are in the orders.  You generally don't want to have, say, a comma separated list or something as a column on your tables, you have a relation table instead.  It will make your life a lot easier.